NextAuth redirects to Twitter and does not come back
I've got the following issue on Android only and ios with Chrome. When I try to do auth with Twitter(x), it redirects to the Twitter app, and does not come back to my website.
This problem is not happening on ios, because it does not redirect to Twitter apps.
I am using next with nextauth
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import TwitterProvider from "next-auth/providers/twitter";

import { adapter } from "@/app/lib/prisma";

export const config = {
  adapter: adapter,
  trustHost: true,
  theme: {
    logo: "/favicon.png",
  },
  providers: [
    TwitterProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_TWITTER_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET ?? "",
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
  
  ],
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ request, auth }) {
      const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
      if (pathname === "/middleware-example") return !!auth;
      return true;
    },
    jwt({ token, trigger, session }) {
      if (trigger === "update") token.name = session.user.name;
      return token;
    },
  },

  basePath: "/api/auth",



} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config);

How can I prevent the redirect to Twitter app?

Use Custom Redirect URLs
Make sure that your callbackUrl is correctly set, and explicitly define it when using the signIn() function:
signIn('twitter', { callbackUrl: 'https://yourwebsite.com' });


still redirects to x app and does nothing there

The issue you're experiencing with NextAuth and Twitter login on Android and iOS (Chrome) where the app redirects to Twitter but doesn't come back is likely related to how mobile operating systems handle app redirects. On Android and iOS, Twitter’s app could be hijacking the authentication flow when the user is redirected to the Twitter app for login, and then it fails to return to your website properly.

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/v4/packages/next-auth/src/providers/twitter.ts

and how can i fix this ? on some other apps is working just fine
